# how to filter an array of objects based on property value of another array object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I need to filter b based on name property and I need only those columns in b

```
     a = [{'id':'1', 'name':'a1'}, {'id':'2', 'name':'a4'}]

     b = [{'a1':'2', 'a2':'3','a3':'2', 'a4':'3' }, {'a1':'5', 
        'a2':'7','a3':'9', 'a4':'6' } ]

     c = [{'a1':'2','a4':'3' }, {'a1':'5','a4':'6' }]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   let filterData = [];
   b.map(data => {
      let obj = {};
      a.forEach(cols => {
        obj[cols.name] = data[cols.name]
      })
      filterData.push(obj)
    });
```

Comment: while this code may answer the question, adding some explanation on why and how it solves it will improve the quality of the answer.